# How reliable is AWS APAC cross regions for Disaster Recovery?

Tags: amazon-web-services, disaster-recovery

I need to choose 2 pair Regions for my disaster recovery setup in APAC domain.
There are 5 possible regions in APAC :

```
Asia Pacific (Mumbai)
Asia Pacific (Seoul)
Asia Pacific (Singapore)
Asia Pacific (Sydney)
Asia Pacific (Tokyo)
```

I need to choose the best pairs among these regions for disaster recovery. The parameters i want to compare are :

1. as close as possible (for lowest latency possible)
2. geopolitical separation (no common political turmoils)
3. power grid separation (no shared power grid)
4. regional stability (no common military enemies)
5. geographic separation (no common natural disasters)

Can someone guide me on this?